# Как создать и связать базу данных для Yii2?

Tags: mysql, база-данных, ubuntu, yii2, yii

Только-только начал изучать MySQL в связи с установкой приложения на сервер с фреймворком Yii2

Страница установки:

[image: страница установки]

В mysql создал БД, условно asdfbase без таблиц

Так же пользователя asdf с паролем pass с доступом ко всем таблицам

Ввожу все данные соответственно.

Название: asdfbase
логин: asdf
пароль: pass

После чего выдает ошибку

array(1) { ["dberror"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(111) "Не удалось подключиться к БД: asdf:pass:asdfbase:localhost could not find driver" } } app\controllers\SiteController::actionInstall

По какой причине может подключиться к БД?

Comment: Ну собсно тебе вроде вменяемо пишут: *could not find driver*... попробуй для начала в db.php поменять `localhost` на `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: @Akina изменил. ошибка та же

Comment: Тогда ещё укажите пользователя полностью - включая хост (`asdf@127.0.0.1`). И убедитесь, что созданный в MySQL пользователь точно такой же - и имя, и хост совпадают. Для проверки - попробуйте подключиться консольным клиентом (mysql.exe) от имени этого пользователя. Если не поможет - читайте доки на уй и на пых по этой ошибке... а ещё проверьте, загружен ли модуль *pdo_mysql* (см. вывод `phpinfo()`).

Comment: @Akina установил php5.6-mysql. Похоже, что сработало

Comment: @Akina только теперь ошибки по бд вылазят
https://habrastorage.org/webt/5c/08/db/5c08db449ef2a239512760.jpeg
https://habrastorage.org/webt/5c/08/db/5c08db4d1af88509025231.jpeg
https://habrastorage.org/webt/5c/08/db/5c08db56366d3640693405.jpeg

Comment: Ну нет поля `country` в таблице `clicks`... тут уж, извините, ничем не помочь, если структура БД не соответствует тому, на что рассчитывает программа.